# Gitlab CI/CD - the connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, minikube, cicd

I build a spring boot project and I want to deploy it to minikube using GitLab CI/CD. I'm able to deploy the application by directly accessing the deployment.yml from local machine.

But I'm getting the following error when I tried to deploy it from GitLab.

Error

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-management
spec:
  # the target number of Pods
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-management
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-management
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-management7
          image: registry.gitlab.com/PROFILE_NAME/user-management
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8082
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.gitlab.com
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
  - mysql:8

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - test
  - deploy-tb
  - deploy-prod

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/PROFILE_NAME/user-management .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/PROFILE_NAME/user-management

test:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  services:
    - mysql:8
  script:
    - "mvn clean test"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

deploy-tb:
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: [ "" ]
  stage: deploy-tb
  script:
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
  environment:
    name: prod
    url: registry.gitlab.com/PROFILE_NAME/user-management
```

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: your gitlab pipeline needs a valid kubeconfig. there probable isn't one in $HOME/.kube/config which is why he tries a default api-server under localhost:8080 where obviously your cluster is not reachable in

Answer (score 0):

According to GitLab documentation, you need first to install the [GitLab Agent for Kubernetes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/).

These are the steps for the installation process:

> To install the Agent in your cluster:
>
> 1. [Define a configuration repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#define-a-configuration-repository).
> 2. [Register an agent with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#register-an-agent-with-gitlab).
> 3. [Install the agent into the cluster](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#install-the-agent-into-the-cluster).

Note: On self-managed GitLab instances, a GitLab administrator needs to set up the [GitLab Agent Server (KAS)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/clusters/kas.html).

Comment: @Anne was this answer useful to you?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @Anne. In my case, I'm using kind, not minikube, to run a local Kubernetes cluster within a GitLab pipeline, but like her, I'm also getting a connection refused error. Essentially, kubectl is unable to connect to the cluster's control plane. I had hoped that telling minikube/kind to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 would do the trick, but that didn't help unfortunately. Does the documentation you provided only apply if you want your pipeline to have access to an external Kubernetes cluster? Or does it also apply to local Kubernetes clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in my case, I used `kind` instead of `minikube`.

1. Tell `kind`/`minikube` to bind to port `0.0.0.0`.

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
networking:
  apiServerAddress: "0.0.0.0"
```

```
kind create cluster --config kind-config.yml --wait 60s
```

2. Tell `kubectl` to look for the cluster's control plane at the IP address of Docker's default bridge network.

```
- REAL_IP=$(ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
- sed -i -e "s/0.0.0.0/$REAL_IP/g" $HOME/.kube/config
```

https://gist.github.com/trondhindenes/0307fbe9cda1164115353b4632a31ea9?permalink_comment_id=4712719#gistcomment-4712719